# Add README.md to local repository from GitHub

Tags: git, github

How can I add the `README.md` file from GitHub repository to my local repository?

My repository is initialized and I have made some commits which I pushed to GitHub. After that I added `README.md` on GitHub. Now I want to add it to my local repo too.

I searched extensively but could not find any answers.

Comment: How about `git pull origin`?

Comment: It says, "You asked to pull from remote but did not specify branch."

Comment: Then `git pull origin master`...

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Why don't you add an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Did you really search extensively? May some book/tutorial on git? This is basic information to work with git

Comment: I tried for an hour. Ended up deleting readme.

Comment: Here's a link for you... https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the changes from your remote repository merged into your local clone, you have to use the `git pull` command:

```
git pull origin master
```

This tells Git to pull in the changes from the remote branch `master` on the remote `origin` into your current local branch.

Comment: Will this overwrite the changes I have made locally? I added a readme and then went ahead and did a lot of stuff in my local repository. Now I want to commit and push and I have this issue as there is a README.md in the remote repo but not in my local. :(